# Find all documents between 2 keys inclusive (ranged key search) - MongoDB

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

I am Emulating Firebase Realtime DB's REST GET endpoint's `startAt` and `endAt` filters using MongoDB and FastAPI.

I am aware of the $gt and $lt query filters for fields in MongoDB and these work great with numerical values but act kind of weird when comparing values between strings.

Firebase's functionality will find all the key-value pairs between 2 keys passed in the `startAt` & `endAt` filters. For example,

```json
{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 11, "d": 43, "ax": 31}
```

The API Call looks like

```bash
https://test-5681a-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/sample.json?orderBy="$key"&startAt="b"&endAt="d"
```

Returns

```json
{"b": 2, "c": 11, "d": 43}
```

### Replicating this functionality using MongoDB's query

MongoDB collections comprise JSON documents, while Firebase Realtime DB is a JSON document itself. When trying to replicate such behavior with MongoDB query for string comparisons with

Sample data:

```json
[
    {
        "_fm_id": "1",
        "_fm_val": {
            "userId": 1,
            "firstName": "Krish",
            "lastName": "Lee",
            "phoneNumber": "123456",
            "emailAddress": "krish.lee@learningcontainer.com"
        }
    },
    {
        "_fm_id": "2",
        "_fm_val": {
            "userId": 2,
            "firstName": "racks",
            "lastName": "jacson",
            "phoneNumber": "123456",
            "emailAddress": "racks.jacson@learningcontainer.com"
        }
    },
    {
        "_fm_id": "3",
        "_fm_val": {
            "userId": 3,
            "firstName": "denial",
            "lastName": "roast",
            "phoneNumber": "33333333",
            "emailAddress": "denial.roast@learningcontainer.com"
        }
    },
    {
        "_fm_id": "4",
        "_fm_val": {
            "userId": 4,
            "firstName": "devid",
            "lastName": "neo",
            "phoneNumber": "222222222",
            "emailAddress": "devid.neo@learningcontainer.com"
        }
    },
    {
        "_fm_id": "5",
        "_fm_val": {
            "userId": 5,
            "firstName": "jone",
            "lastName": "mac",
            "phoneNumber": "111111111",
            "emailAddress": "jone.mac@learningcontainer.com"
        }
    },
    {
        "_fm_id": "0605e7bc80884477b71a3675c77e5a80",
        "_fm_val": {
            "userId": 90,
            "firstName": "Harish",
            "lastName": "Nathuram",
            "phoneNumber": "7289338473",
            "emailAddress": "harish.nathu@yahoo.com"
        }
    }
]
```

Expecting the query to return

```json
[
    {
        "_fm_id": "3",
        "_fm_val": {
            "userId": 3,
            "firstName": "denial",
            "lastName": "roast",
            "phoneNumber": "33333333",
            "emailAddress": "denial.roast@learningcontainer.com"
        }
    },
    {
        "_fm_id": "4",
        "_fm_val": {
            "userId": 4,
            "firstName": "devid",
            "lastName": "neo",
            "phoneNumber": "222222222",
            "emailAddress": "devid.neo@learningcontainer.com"
        }
    },
    {
        "_fm_id": "5",
        "_fm_val": {
            "userId": 5,
            "firstName": "jone",
            "lastName": "mac",
            "phoneNumber": "111111111",
            "emailAddress": "jone.mac@learningcontainer.com"
        }
    }
]
```

Can this be done by comparing `firstName`? - Write a Mongo Query

```py
db.user.find(
  {"_fm_val.firstName": {"$gt": "denial", "$lt": "jone"}}, 
  {"_id": 0}
)
```

Comment: I wrote an answer below based on my initial understanding, but now realize you may actually be asking how to filter on MongoDB's API. If that's the case, you might want to reduce the question to include less mention of Firebase, to prevent others from misinterpreting it too.

Comment: Yeah, I will modify the question a bit...
I want to emulate that behavior using MongoDB's query

Comment: I found out that Firebase Real-time Database sort items lexicograhically